# Using Regression in R - Prediction doesn't match actual

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I am using R to build a model and using last year's billing data to predict collection amounts. Comparing the predicted values vs. actuals, the numbers are way off. I'm expecting collections of thousands, but the prediction has values like 1.022445e+07.

```
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(dataset$TotalCollected, SplitRatio = 0.8)
training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)

regressor = lm(formula = TotalCollected ~ CntBillableCAMs + TotalBill + TotalWorkedHrs + global1000_flg + fort1000_flg, #all independent variables separated by +
               data = training_set)

summary(regressor)


y_pred = predict(regressor, newdata = test_set)


Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3082854   -15118     3281    17832  5494125 

                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)      
(Intercept)     -3.747e+03  6.144e+03  -0.610  0.54199   
Cnts             9.218e+01  4.255e+01   2.167  0.03038 *    
TotalBill        4.699e-01  2.664e-02  17.643  < 2e-16 `***`  
TotalWorkedHrs   1.562e+02  1.523e+01  10.259  < 2e-16 `***`  
global1000_flg   1.362e+05  4.816e+04   2.828  0.00472 **   
fort1000_flg    -6.044e+04  2.738e+04  -2.207  0.02739 *   

Residual standard error: 263100 on 2094 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7694    
Adjusted R-squared:  0.7689  
F-statistic:  1397 on 5 and 2094 DF  
p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

None of my p-values exceed .05 - Let me know if you need to see them. They don't copy well.

Thank you for any guidance.

EDIT: Formatting

Comment: Have you looked at `summary(training_set)` and  `summary(test_set)`?  It might be that your `test_set` contains observations with values considerably different to your `training_set`.

Comment: Try to get the confidence interval, instead of point estimate 1.022445e+07 alone. Then check if CI cover your expected collection.

Comment: When I changed to the training_set in the regressor and the prediction, the values looked more in line with expectations. Not quite good enough yet, but at least they're making sense. Thanks.

Comment: @slackline - If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: thanks @a_statistician - I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at `summary(training_set)` and `summary(test_set)`? It might be that your `test_set` contains observations with values considerably different to your `training_set`.